# Maximum declared length of a column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a python dataframe with certain columns whose length has been hardcoded to some values like 40, 50 etc. I want to get this maximum declared length. Could someone please help

Comment: Your question is unclear and too broad, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to understand how to ask a good question

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear, but I think following code may help you.
Following example code finds the length of the longest string/field in the column named `'col#1'`.

```
maxWidth = df['col#1'].map(len).max()
```

Comment: Another option, with the `str` accessor: `df['col'].str.len()`.

Comment: @Chinmay Ibwant to get the maximum possible length for which the column is defined like at first I am defining the length to be 60 amd I want to get it displayed

Comment: @Mevin, It could be that I am not getting your problem. Can you explain your problem with an example code with input and desired output so that others can understand better and you can get help quicker.

Comment: @Chinmay I am defining the length of a column of data frame as follows. Df['name']= Df['name'].apply(lambda x:str(x)[:60]) . Now I want to get this max length specified.

Comment: Df['name'].map(len).max() should work for you.
REASON: Note that with the above  method you are infact putting a limit on the length of the strings in that column 'name' upto a maximum of 60 characters.
The size you specified is not stored any attribute/property of the dataframe, it simply truncates the column value if length exceeds the specified size.

Comment: @Chinmay Actually I want to get that limit that we have kept on the column

Comment: The limit you specified is not stored anywhere, it is just used to truncate the longer strings from the column with your specified limit. Sorry I could not be of any help.